# Stripplot color points based on date

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-science, seaborn

I have a data which has various values of A, B, C and D based different dates, i want to make a stripplot of these points, such that data points of recent date should be shaded darker(or have more alpha value) compared data points of previous dates.

this is what i have right now, all i need is to shade the points based on date for each bucket. but i am not able to figure that out

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mlp
plt.style.use("ggplot")

data = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(start="2020-01-06", end="2020-08-10", freq="W-MON"),
                  "A":[np.random.randint(-5, 50) for _ in range(len(pd.date_range(start="2020-01-06", end="2020-08-10", freq="W-MON")))],
                  "B":[np.random.randint(-5, 50) for _ in range(len(pd.date_range(start="2020-01-06", end="2020-08-10", freq="W-MON")))],
                  "C":[np.random.randint(-10, 50) for _ in range(len(pd.date_range(start="2020-01-06", end="2020-08-10", freq="W-MON")))],
                  "D":[np.random.randint(9, 50) for _ in range(len(pd.date_range(start="2020-01-06", end="2020-08-10", freq="W-MON")))]})
data.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
data.head()
sns.catplot(data=data, aspect=15/6, height=6)
```

This is the result of the above code
[image]

Comment: Do you mean darkest color below and lighter color above?Did you try with the `hue` parameter?

Comment: Yes, i did it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scatter plot with randomized x-displacements can be used to apply one colormap per column.

To illustrate the effect, the example below uses random data with the most recent values being the largest.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use("ggplot")
dates = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-06", end="2020-08-10", freq="W-MON")
N = len(dates)
data = pd.DataFrame({"Date": dates,
                     "A": 30 + np.random.uniform(-5, 8, N).cumsum(),
                     "B": 20 + np.random.uniform(-4, 9, N).cumsum(),
                     "C": 25 + np.random.uniform(-4, 7, N).cumsum(),
                     "D": 40 + np.random.uniform(-2, 8, N).cumsum()})
data.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
columns = data.columns
for col_id, (column, cmap) in enumerate(zip(columns, ['Reds', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Purples'])):
    plt.scatter(col_id + np.random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2, N), data[column], c=range(N), cmap=cmap)
plt.xticks(range(len(columns)), columns)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly for me.!